# How do i auto-populate fields in django?

Tags: django, forms, integration-testing

I have a model Question with a field called **userid**, before one ask a question, one needs to login, i want when saving to capture the user ID of the currently logged-in user and assign it to the userid of the Question model.

Please note am not showing the userid on my form i.e. in the Question model i have declared the userid as follows;

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
   userid=models.ForeignKey(User, editable=false)
   ...
```

How do i assign logged-in user ID to the Question model `userid`?

Comment: As a sidenote, it would be more sensible and clearer to call your field "user" rather than "userid"; as the attribute actually refers to a User object, not an id number. Django will automatically create the DB field with '_id' appended; so as you have it now that's "userid_id".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code may look like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Question

@login_required
def ask(request):
    form = QuestionForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        question = form.save(False)
        question.userid = request.user
        question.save()

    #...
```